# Resharper FIler layout not applying when using code cleanup?

Tags: resharper

I am trying to learn to use file layout and For now I just wanted my static fields to be sorted according to access modifiers. First private and then public .
I created a file layout and then used code cleanup but nothing changes in my code. please help
[image]

[image]

XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Patterns xmlns="urn:schemas-jetbrains-com:member-reordering-patterns">
  <FilePattern>
    <Entry DisplayName="Sort statics">
      <Entry.Match>
        <Static />
      </Entry.Match>
      <Entry.SortBy>
        <Access />
        <Name />
      </Entry.SortBy>
    </Entry>
  </FilePattern>
</Patterns>
```

Comment: I assume you have read this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_and_Type_Layout.html#reordering-file-and-type-members

Comment: @PiersMyers yeah I did this as well. created a custom profile and used that for code cleanup but still no result.

Comment: Does the default 'out of the box' rules wok? If so then modify them to your liking. Are you using the latest version of ReSharper? If you think it's a bug then you can raise it directly with Jetbrains.

Comment: You use a "File pattern" in your sample. If you re-read the web help article (mentioned by @PiersMyers above), it says that you have to use a "Type pattern" instead. As I understand you want to sort type members, but a "File pattern" can't help you here. Check the "Introduction to layout patterns" section on the article page.

Comment: @PiersMyers I don't know whether its a bug or I am doing something wrong as its my first time and I even tried changing the default one but still no result. 
Anyways, for the time being I am using codemaid its simple and intuitive.

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin same result even with Type pattern. If possible can you send me your type layout  XAML code which sort statics fields by their access modifier and then by its name and so that I can check if its  a bug or some mistake from my end

Comment: @karansharma I've added the XAML code for the File Layout in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern (now it has the "Fields" region you showed on the video)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Patterns xmlns="urn:schemas-jetbrains-com:member-reordering-patterns">
  <TypePattern DisplayName="Default Pattern">
    <Region Name="Fields">
      <Entry DisplayName="Sort static by access modifier" Priority="100">
        <Entry.Match>
          <And>
            <Kind Is="Field" />
            <Static />
          </And>
        </Entry.Match>
        <Entry.SortBy>
          <Access Order="Private Protected ProtectedInternal Internal Public" />
          <Name />
        </Entry.SortBy>
      </Entry>
    </Region>
  </TypePattern>
</Patterns>
```

Comment: Its still not working maybe I am doing something wrong. 
here is a short clip of what I have done--
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/697845282309931012/809288113850810369/bandicam_2021-02-11_10-29-15-299.mp4

Comment: There are two problems here. The first one - File Layout can be applied only to the whole file, not just to a few lines, so you have to run the Code Cleanup for the file. The second one is that you have already had a region in your code. By default, ReSharper does not touch code inside regions, if these regions are not specified in the File Layout pattern. I've updated the code snippet to reflect the `Fields` region.